# How to scrape the page one is currently on using cheerio and node.js?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

So this might be a convoluted question, but here goes:

I'm creating a simple, locally hosted web scraper with node.js. It's working perfectly fine when I manually define the URL to be scraped in the source file, and I'm now trying to prompt the user for a URL of their choice. I then append the URL they've entered to an empty div, and ideally, would be able to use cheerio to grab the content of that div.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to parse the data that is being created on the same page that the script is running on. Any insight would be much, much appreciated!

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");

    response.write('<div id="newsStory"></div>');
    response.write("<script type='text/javascript'>var userPrompt = prompt('input a url');");
    response.write("if(userPrompt) {document.getElementById('newsStory').innerHTML = userPrompt;}");
    response.write("</script>");

    var $ = cheerio.load();

    var url = $('div#newsStory').text(); //does not work!

    var url = "http://www.cnn.com/2013/09/23/us/south-carolina-powerball-winner/"; //manually inputting a url works!
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is you're mixing the browser-side DOM with the document Cheerio has server-side. The div `newsStory` is client-side, so you have to find some way to send its contents to the server.

Since you're familiar with Cheerio syntax, you could use jQuery on the client side, where the `text()` method acts the same, and you could use `$.post()` to send the URL to the server.

Comment: hey, that's a great idea! I'll try that out and let you know what I find. thanks!